# How to check the date if the condition required is greater than and less than the current date in php?

Tags: php

What is my need from below code is!, I am getting output has "**completed**" and "**Pending**". How should I Get "Reached the limit" has output.

The conditions Need

- If `$current` date greater than `$next_due_on_date` it should shows
  output has "Pending".
- In this condition, I need notification like "30 Days for expiry" i.e. before `$next_due_on_date` reach its limit.
- If `$current` date less than `$next_due_on_date` it should shows output has "Completed".

Please Help me to Solve the Logic.
Thanks!

```
$current_date = date('Y-m-d G:i:s');   //Current date
$next_due_on_date = '24/10/2018';    //$next_due_on
$next_due_on_date = str_replace('/', '-', $next_due_on_date); //Replacing the format with str_replace       
$highlight_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("$next_due_on_date 0 years 0 months -30 days"));    //$highlight_date is to subtract the next_due_on_date with -30 days
if($current_date <= $highlight_date){
    $output = "Completed";
}elseif($current_date > $highlight_date){
    $output = "Pending";
}else{
    $output = "Reached the limit"
}
print_r($output);
```

Comment: can you further explain about the second point?

Comment: for ex: If $current_date is "25-09-2018" and $next_due_on_date  is"25-10-2018". Already i said $highlight_date subtract -30 days before the $next_due_on_date. So, if my output is in between from $current_date to -30 days of the next_due_on_date reach the limit. Output to show is "30 Days remaining to expiry"

Comment: You missed `;` on `$output = "Reached the limit";`

Comment: @Arun explain this `In this condition, I need notification like "30 Days for expiry" i.e. before $next_due_on_date reach its limit`

Comment: Why dont you try by using `strttotime()` function. For example $current_date = strtotime(date('Y-m-d G:i:s'));
    $next_due_on_date = strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $next_due_on_date));

    if( $current_date <= $next_due_on_date ){
        //some code
    }

Comment: @Chonchol Mahmud, I placed the ; Still can't get the output

Comment: you'll never come to else part unless you remove `=` from here `if($current_date <= $highlight_date){`

Comment: @TarangP, Can you give me any brief examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@Arun` I didnt Understand your requirement properly But as far i understand you can try like this.

```
<?php

function s2t($value){
    return strtotime($value);
}

$date1 = 
$date2 = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('+30days'));
$date3 = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('-30days'));

if( s2t($date1) > s2t($date2)  ){
    echo "30+ Days left";
}else{
    echo "30 Days Left";
}
```

Comment: I got it. Thanks.

Comment: it's my pleasure to answer

Answer (score 0):

Arun,

I noticed a few things in your code. The main issue here is that you said you wanted to get the **Reached the limit**, but your `IF` does not allow this happen.

Let me explain why: first you compare if `$current_date <= $highlight_date`, then you compare if `$current_date > $highlight_date`. As *current_date* can only be <= or > than *highlight_date*, the last `else` will never run.

So you need to restructure your IFs, to get that.

I am not sure if I understand very well your points, but if I did you want to:

1. Compare if `$current_date <= ($next_due_on_date - 30 days))`
2. Elseif `$current_date <= $next_due_on_date`
3. Else...

So it would be something like this (I tried to change as little as possible your code):

```
$current_date = date('Y-m-d G:i:s');   //Current date
$next_due_on_date = '24/10/2018';    //$next_due_on
$next_due_on_date = str_replace('/', '-', $next_due_on_date); //Replacing the format with str_replace       
$highlight_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("$next_due_on_date 0 years 0 months -30 days"));    //$highlight_date is to subtract the next_due_on_date with -30 days
if($current_date <= $highlight_date){
    $output = "Completed";
}elseif($current_date <= $next_due_on_date){
    $output = "Pending";
}else{
    $output = "Reached the limit";
}
print_r($output);
```

Is it that?

Comment: When will i "Reach the Limit" or it will never!

Comment: When current_date were greater than $next_due_on_date. :)

Comment: Sorry If current_date were greater than $next_due_on_date still the output is "Pending"

Comment: Bruno F. Fontes, It's ok. No worries!

Comment: Huum, what so what are all the rules?

Comment: I can't get you.

Answer (score 0):

The code below is working well. please check, it may use for any concept which you want to compare the two dates.

```
$current_date = date('Y-m-d G:i:s');
$next_due_on_date = '27/09/2018';
$next_due_on_date = str_replace('/', '-', $next_due_on_date);        
$highlight_lesser_thirdty_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("$next_due_on_date 0 years 0 months -30 days"));
$highlight_lesser_thirdtyone_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("$next_due_on_date 0 years 1 months -31 days"));
if(($current_date <= $highlight_lesser_thirdtyone_date ) && ($current_date <= $highlight_lesser_thirdty_date)) {
     $status = "Completed";
}elseif(($current_date < $highlight_lesser_thirdtyone_date) && ($current_date > $highlight_lesser_thirdty_date)){
     $status = "Calibration to be conducted";
}elseif($current_date < $next_due_on_date){
     $status = "Pending";
}
print_r($calibration_status);
```